# C# Forms - Using Paint methods?

Tags: c#, forms, drawing, polygon, graphic

In c# forms I have created a new paint method:

```
private void thisPolygon(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen clrBlue = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
    Point[] Wst = new Point[5];
    Wst[0] = new Point(20, 350);
    Wst[1] = new Point(110, 200);
    Wst[2] = new Point(200, 190);
    Wst[3] = new Point(210, 275);
    Wst[4] = new Point(190, 400);
    Wst[5] = new Point(50, 390);
    e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(clrBlue, Wst);
}
```

Now, how do I call it? I can't make it work, this doesn't work:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thisPolygon(); ///I've tried adding some stuff in brackets area, failed.
}
```

Comment: The Load event is called when the form is...loaded. Put it inside the Paint event (it's called to paint the form client area) or override the OnPaint() method.

Comment: I did, I failed and now I'm here. Hi :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few different problems.

(1) **Array Capacity**. Your array is initialized with 5 storage locations, but you are attempting to set a sixth value.

```
Point[] Wst = new Point[5]; // 5 indexes
...
Wst[5] = new Point(50, 390); // Tries to access a sixth, but is out of bounds
```

Change this to.

```
Point[] Wst = new Point[6];
```

Remember that arrays are zero-based indexed.

(2) **Not using OnPaint**. You're calling `thisPolygon` in the `OnLoad` method, which won't persist your drawing. Move your call to the `OnPaint` method of the form.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    thisPolygon();
}
```

(3) **Not passing PaintEventArgs**. You're not passing in any event arguments to your `thisPolygon` method, and it won't even compile as it is. Pass in the paint arguments from the `OnPaint` method.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e); // Pass in e
    thisPolygon();
}
```