# Drawing on a panel c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, drawing

I need to graph a polygonal on a panel (size 400, 400)
I try this, but it doesn't work.

```
PointF[] points = new PointF[totalpaso + 1];
for (int d = 0; d <= totalpaso; d++)
{
    s = (float)(hola1[d] + 200);
    w = (float)(hola2[d] + 200);
    j = new PointF(s, w);
    points[d] = j;
}
grafico.DrawPolygon(lapiz, points);
```

Comment: _doesnt work_ is never enough information about a problem. What do you mean it? You get any exception or error message? Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: The panel doesn't change. I mean, i execute it but nothing appears on the panel. I dont get any exception or error message.

Comment: @JoaquínCastilloSilva You need to show more of your code. All painting work needs to be done on OnPaint, otherwise you won't see the results until you invalidate the region that you painted on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at this post: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07e699tw(v=vs.110).aspx

But with only that method you won't get far. It'll be drawn in a OnPaint Method: 
[C# Forms - Using Paint methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581599/c-sharp-forms-using-paint-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to make your own control based on Panel.

A really basic example is this:

```
public sealed class MyPanel: Panel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

To test it, add the class to a Windows Forms project, compile, and then drop it onto a form and set it to "Dock" in the designer.

Then set the BackColor to, say, red and the ForeColor to blue, then run the program.

You can then add your required drawing code to the `OnPaint()` override.